# How can I pass a dynamic height to Leaflet CRS map in my Ionic 3 App?

Tags: leaflet

I am using Leaflet to render a floor plan map on my page. I am able to render my image, but because a user can upload any size of map, I need to be able to account for that.

I am capturing the height/width when the image is uploaded, but not sure how to pass that to my view.

I am trying this (without much luck):

```
<div #map id="map" ng-style="{'height' : '{{ myObject.mapHeight }}px' }"></div>
```

`mapHeight` is available in my `.ts` file. and I can output it to the view to check that a value is actually coming through. What is the best way to pass the image height to the view?

Here is my `.ts` file:

```
map: L.Map = null;
@ViewChild('map') mapContainer: ElementRef;


...

this.map = L.map(this.mapContainer.nativeElement, {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple,
});


let geoJson = L.geoJSON(this.geoData, {
  style: function (feature) {
    return {
      weight: 0.8
    }
  },
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    //
  }
}).addTo(this.map);

let bounds: any = [[0, 0], [this.myObject.mapHeight, this.myObject.mapWidth]];
let image: any = L.imageOverlay(this.myObject.mapUrl, bounds).addTo(this.map);

this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

**EDIT**

If I do this, I can get the height, but watching the logs, it seems this method just runs and runs and runs. I can immagine at some point I'll consume all memory and that's no good.

```
<div #map id="map" [ngStyle]="getMapStyle()"></div>
```

**.ts**

```
...
getMapStyle() {
    console.log('--> getMapStyle called');
    console.log('map height: ', this.mapHeight + 'px');

    return {
      'height': this.myObject.mapHeight + 'px'
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to do the same, here is what ended up working for me.

**.html**

```
<div #map id="map" [style.height.px]="myObject?.mapHeight"></div>
```